# 24-bit Custom Target

Tags: rust, llvm, rust-cargo, texas-instruments

I'm trying to compile for a custom target that has a 24-bit pointer (the eZ80). I'm now stuck wondering if that's even possible in the current Rust toolchain?

I tried creating a custom target file with `"data-layout"` set to `"e-m:z-p:24:8-p1:16:8-p2:8:8-p3:16:8-p4:24:8-i16:8-i24:8-i32:8-i48:8-i64:8-i96:8-f32:8-f64:8-a:8-n8:16:24-S8"` and `"target-pointer-width"` set to `"24"`, but rustc errors with `error: target specification was invalid: unrecognized target-pointer-width 24`. Sticking to the possible pointer widths of 16, 32, and 64, I went with 32 since that's closest, but this fails with `error: inconsistent target specification: "data-layout" claims pointers are 24-bit, while "target-pointer-width" is '32'`.

I'm not quite sure how to resolve this, since compiling with 32-bit pointers leads to some weird linker errors with "index half registers".

Comment: I sadly am not sure if Rust currently supports 24-bit systems. The possible values of [`target_pointer_width`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_pointer_width) seem to suggest that it doesn't.

Comment: You'll have to work on the rust compiler. There are a couple of possible ways to approach this, but all involve working on the rust compiler and/or runtime library. LLVM's pointer size for the eZ80 are effectively unchangeable, because the eZ80 fixes those. A compiler can't really target a different register size than the CPU actually has.